# Turn off shading

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I know this is probably a super easy answer, but I can't find it anywhere.
How do I turn the shading off on objects when I got them in texture mode? I want to fully see the texture without the crazy dark shadows; preferably no shadows at all.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so when you go into texture mode, you want to press "n" on your keyboard.
Scroll down, and near the bottom of the list you will see "shading". click on it, and you will see this:
[image]
Click on "Shadeless" and there you go! No more shade!

Comment: Sure thing! glad to help!